# ¿Cómo puedo enviar mediante Ajax en un bucle for y no se siga ejecutando hasta que envíe?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, sql-server

Antes de nada Gracias.
Yo tengo un bucle donde quiero hacer **varios POST a un php desde AJAX** pero quiero que hasta que no termine el POST no  se siga ejecutando el bucle.
Dejo código:
PD: Ese archivo php hace un insert a una base de datos SQL, me gustaría saber si es posible saber desde javaScript cuando termina de hacerse el insert y de paso no seguir ejecutando el for hasta que se ejecute cada insert. (cualqueira de las dos maneras me serviría

```
for (let i = 0; i < cantidad; i++) { 

                n = 0;
                n++;
                numeroCodeBar = parseInt(numeroCodeBar) + n;
                var resultado = cadenaNumerica + numeroCodeBar;
                resultado = resultado.toString().substring(resultado.length - cadenaNumerica.length);
                var f = new Date();
                var fechaActual = f.getDate() + "-" + (f.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + f.getFullYear();
                var codeBar = departamento.value + sociedad.value + tipoAF.value + anio.value.substring(2, 4) + resultado;
                var subcodigo = departamento.value + '-' + sociedad.value + '-' + tipoAF.value + '-' + anio.value.substring(2, 4) + '-' + resultado;
                var infoParaEnviar = {
                    departamento: departamento.value,
                    sociedad: sociedad.value,
                    tipoAF: tipoAF.value,
                    anio: anio.value,
                    fechaActual: fechaActual,
                    codeBar: codeBar,
                    subcodigo: subcodigo
                };

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "php/insertar.php",
                        data: infoParaEnviar,
                        dataType: "text",
                        asycn: true,
                        success: function () {
                        }
                    });

            }
```

Si no me explico bien díganmelo eh intentaré editar la pregunta

Comment: En el código de arriba tienes `asycn: true`, eso quiere decir que va a lanzar todas las request independientemente de que la anterior haya finalizado. En programación asíncrona lo que hacemos tipicamente es lanzar la siguiente request en la función `success` de la request anterior, o con `done()`. Otra opción es no usar programación asíncrona.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la puse a falso y sigue insertando datos de  manera desordenada, no consecutivamente. Me gustaría que pusieras un ejemplo de como enviar los datos de manera no asíncrona.  Gracias de nuevo

Comment: Ajax síncrono es una mala idea: congelará la UI. Por otro lado no entiendo el uso de la variable `n`: en cada iteración se pone a 0 y acto seguido se pone a 1... algo no está bien, aparte de las llamadas ajax

Comment: Intento aportar claridad: n no está declarada (¿se crea como global o estará declarada fuera del bucle?). Se inicializa en cada iteración (siempre vale 1) y se usa una sola vez. Todo esto hace que piense que el código está incompleto y por tanto la respuesta puede no ajustarse a lo que realmente necesita

Answer (score 2):

A ver qué te parece esta aproximación:

1. Creas un array con los datos que quieres meter:

   ```
   let datos=[]
   for (...) {
     ... // Lo que necesites para preparar los datos a enviar
     datos.push({
       departamento: departamento.value,
       sociedad: sociedad.value,
       tipoAF: tipoAF.value,
       anio: anio.value,
       fechaActual: fechaActual,
       codeBar: codeBar,
       subcodigo: subcodigo
     });
   }
   ```
2. Y entonces haces que la llamada ajax, al ser respondida, se repita con el siguiente dato del array:

   ```
   function nextCall(d) {
     return $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "php/insertar.php",
       data: d,
       dataType: "text",
     });
   }

   let ajaxPromise=nextCall(datos.shift());

   while(datos.length) {
     ajaxPromise=ajaxPromise.then(nextCall(datos.shift()));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

En respuesta a lo que me pedías en el comentario, este es un ejemplo sencillo. Básicamente **pones el Ajax adentro de una función** y como en Javascript las funciones son objetos, la puedes pasar directamente como función success.

```
function LanzarAjax()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/api/data",
        success: LanzarAjax
    });
}
```

Ahora bien, cuando el usuario da click en enviar, llamas a la función por primera vez:

```
$("#enviar").click(LanzarAjax);
```

El problema es que eso se ejecutaría para siempre. Entonces agregamos una variable para saber hasta cuando repetir. El código completo es:

```
<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
<script>
    function LanzarAjax(repetir)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(repetir);
                if (repetir > 0)
                {
                    repetir--;
                    LanzarAjax(repetir);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    $("#enviar").click(function () { LanzarAjax(4); });
</script>
```

En consola va imprimiendo 4, 3, 2, 1, 0. Parece que esta api Reqres no da problemas con CORS, entonces la puedes invocar tal cual está en el codigo de arriba. Es mas, puedes agregar `console.log(response);` para que salga en consola el json que va retornando.

Comment: ahora si entendí a lo que se refería,  muchas gracias por la ayuda creo que funcionara, lo voy a probar.